# How can I prevent bundling from using files not included in project?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, .net-4.5

I have an asp.net mvc 5 project using bundling like so:

```
public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
{
    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryui").Include(
            "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-{version}.js"));
}
```

I have one version of jqueryui included in my project, version 1.11.0. However, I also have an older version (1.8.11) on disk in the scripts folder, but not included in the project.

[image]

When I call `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")`, it renders like this (including both the files).

```
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.11.0.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.11.js"></script>
```

Needless to say this causes multiple issues (this happens with css files as well). Obviously I could simply delete the old files, and I do; but I find myself doing that quite frequently, since another branch of the TFS repository has these old files. Every time we merge they come over again.

How can I instruct the bundling engine to ignore files that are not part of the solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot ignore files that are part of the solution because when the web app is running there is no solution file. The publish wizard will not deploy files that are not part of the solution. But if you already have multiple files deployed they will all be rendered. 
I've created this method that grab only the latest one:

```
    public static string[] GetLatestVersion(params string[] files)
    {
        System.Collections.Generic.List<string> latestFiles = new System.Collections.Generic.List<string>();
        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            var folder = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(file);
            var phisicalFolder = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(folder);
            var pattern = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file).Replace("{version}", "*");
            var virtualFile = folder.Replace("\\","/") + "/" + System.IO.Path.GetFileName(System.Linq.Enumerable.First(System.Linq.Enumerable.OrderByDescending(System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(phisicalFolder, pattern), x => x)));
            latestFiles.Add(virtualFile);
        }
        return latestFiles.ToArray();
    }

    public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
    {

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(
                    GetLatestVersion("~/Scripts/modernizr-{version}.js")));
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                    GetLatestVersion("~/Scripts/jquery-*.js")));
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

set version in bundle :

```
public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
{
    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryui").Include(
            "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.11.0.js"));
}
```

Comment: Hmm. I'm not a huge fan of that, I update the versions of many of my other bundled files fairly frequently, I'd have to remember to do it there as well. As a last resort though, I'll do this. Thanks!

Comment: you can use wildcard to force only 1.1xxx with "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.1*.js" like this you are quiet to 1.2xxx :)